# Select and transform child element attribute string value in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wix, xslt-1.0

- *How to extract `File -> Source` value*
- *and assign it as `RegistryValue -> Name`, where `RegistryValue` is injected as a new element with the XSLT provided?*

#### Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="WixSlave.Binaries">
            <Component Id="cmpA1D1BF677641BE2AE700859D8256B0FC" Guid="{B0BF9CBD-8A5D-43C1-B9DE-0A1B5A6BD1DE}">
                <File Id="filC2827DDF7874712A62423151FBE8CE34" Source="$(var.WixSlave.TargetDir)\WixSlave.exe" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpBC6AB890535757A915C99A10445CC74E" Guid="{8726FF82-808A-4736-AD0A-C804A34E494B}">
                <File Id="fil7BD5BE5CD71AC92FF47D1D51A99FEE05" Source="$(var.WixSlave.TargetDir)\WixSlave.exe.config" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="WixSlave.Binaries">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpA1D1BF677641BE2AE700859D8256B0FC" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpBC6AB890535757A915C99A10445CC74E" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

#### XSLT Working Without Variable Name Attribute Value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Copy all attributes and elements to the output. -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:DirectoryRef/wix:Component">
        <Component>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
            <RegistryValue Name="toBeVariableKey" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- To be more specific I would like to read the `File` element attribute `Source="$(var.WixSlave.TargetDir)\WixSlave.exe"` and then transform it to just `WixSlaveexe` **i.e. extract from the source string only letters (a-z, A-Z), starting after last slash**
- And then assign that string to the `RegistryValue` element `Name` attribute, which in the sample is `Name="toBeVariableKey"`, but should become `Name="WixSlaveexe"` for the first `Component`
- For the second `Component` it should be reading from `File` `Source="$(var.WixSlave.TargetDir)\WixSlave.exe.config"` and adding `RegistryValue` with `Name="WixSlaveexeconfig"`, and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an attribute value template to set the **Name**

```
<RegistryValue Name="{substring-after(wix:File/@Source, '\')}" />
```

This should extract the sub-string after the first slash, and assign the result to the attribute **name**.

To remove any dots from the text, you can use the **translate** function, like so

```
<RegistryValue Name="{translate(substring-after(wix:File/@Source, '\'), '.', '')}" />
```

Comment: Brilliant! Tested and works. Do you happen to know how I could also get rid of the dots (blacklisting) or just extract letters (whitelisting)?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I thought that was a typo in your question! I have expanded my answer to explain.

Comment: You're a star. Works as well. I have not tested it with multiple slashes though, I assume it will only return after the last slash instead of returning from the first slash occurence... Thanks again!

Comment: substring-after would return after the first slash, I am afraid. You might need to ask another question about multiple slashes.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. i will get rid of any slashes that get in like this i think: `{translate(translate(substring-after(wix:File/@Source, '\'), '.', ''), '\', '')}`